# how to display an activity when execute method OnDestroy

Tags: android

how to display an activity when leaving an activity, the execution in the method "OnDestroy"

```
protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Bundle savedInstanceState = null;
        this.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //launch a code to display a activity   



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is a `super` call in the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`. Do it like you would start any `Activity`

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

where `CurrentAcivity` is the `Actviity` you are currently in and `NextActivity` is the `Actviity` you want to start.

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Read through the documentation above and pay particular attention to the Activity Lifecycle. You don't have to do this in `onDestroy()` and if this is all you are doing there then you don't need to override `onDestroy()` at all. You can put this anywhere in your code and call `finish()` and `onDestroy()` will be called for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can see the documentation of this method here.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is called when the activity is being created.

You don't call it when you need to create an activity.

In order to start a new activity , call startActivity().